# C++ string checks substring with find_first_of function from std lib

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am tying to use the `find_first_of` function from the C++ lib to check if a string contains a certain substring, the result is not quite what I expected.

I have the code like below

```
const std::wstring_view expected{ L"abc-1" };

const std::wstring_view result = GetResult(); // result = L"abc-2-1" from function return 

if (result.find_first_of(expected) == 0) {
    .....
}
```

When I debug this, the code runs into the if scope which means it found the matching substring from the position "0". Is this how this api expected to work? I think I might be missing something here.

Comment: find_first_of doesn't look for a substring, check the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

Comment: [`find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) does not find a substring

Comment: [Finds the first character equal to one of the characters in the given character sequence.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of). You want [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: Before using a function you should familiarize yourself with it's behavior.  cppreference is a really nice reference site and you can read about your function [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/find_first_of)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I misunderstood the usage of find_first_of. I should have used find.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::basic_string_view::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/find_first_of) returns the position of the first occurrence of any of the characters within the string (or `std::basic_string_view::npos` if none are found).

In other words, it gives the position of the first `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'-'`, `'2'` or `'1'`.

Use [`std::basic_string_view::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/find) to get the position of the first whole substring.

```
if (result.find(expected) == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I misunderstood from the reference doc. You are right, I should choose the find instead of find.